# android market publisher does not show galaxy nexus in available devices

Tags: android, visibility, google-play, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In the Android market publisher account, there is a button, *Show devices* to see on what devices the app is available. 
I searched for Samsung galaxy nexus, and I don't see it in the list. Does that mean, my app is not visible on the Galaxy nexus?

Comment: This question is better suited for android.stackexchange.com

Comment: I posted the same question on the site you mentioned. I get comments saying questions from a developers point of view are off the topic. http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17591/11100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you click show devices, search for 'galaxy nexus'  (without the quotes). I do get two devices.

Comment: I get it now. Looks like Google updated their devices list database.